# How do I clear 'Unable to resolve module' error in React Native Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo, simulator, metro-bundler, expo-router

`npx expo start` gives me

Error: Unable to resolve module ./app/index from /Users/jennyestes/Code/JenniferEstes.github.io/my-portfolio/

and

None of these files exist: *A, B, C..

The metro server is only able to load white screens for the Android simulator, iOS simulator, and web browser ever since instillation of expo-router.

Npm doctor and expo-doctor do not show issues.

I have looked over similar questions in this community and have not found a working solution for my project. Does anyone know how to get through this one? Here's my repo for reference: https://github.com/JenniferEstes/JenniferEstes.github.io